# Braintree Authorization Fingerprint Is Invalid

Tags: android, kotlin, braintree-sandbox

I get this error when implement Braintree to my android app.

`Request for configuration has failed: Authorization fingerprint is invalid. Future requests will retry up to 3 times`

I want to implement "add credit card" feature for customers.

[image]

some details about my android project:

- using gradle: `com.braintreepayments.api:drop-in:3.7.0`
- using kotlin 1.3.50
- compileSdk 28, minSdk 21, targetSdk 28

Please help me.. I will provide any shareable additional info if you requested

NB: I added issue too on braintree git. https://github.com/braintree/braintree-android-drop-in/issues/179